# SQL how to update column in row when column variable is in other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I need help with SQL query:

Here is my draft for example SQL:
[SQL draft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioyUu.png)

I have 5 example rows with some variables in 5 "category" columns: "catid, parentid, parentid2, parentid3 and parentid4" and 6 column as SUM .

I need SQL query to set in eventsheduler or CRON to UPDATE SUM variable for EACH catid with SUM column "sum" from ALL rows which has catid in parentid, parentid2, parentid3 or parentid4 OR catid has parentid like NULL, but there are many rows with this catid in parentid, parentid2, parentid3 or parentid4 - and then I need to update this row with sum from all "sum" columns from rows from that question.

In this example there are 5 rows with catid like 142. 
There are R2 and R3 with 142 as catid. Then I need to update SUM column for R2 and R3 with 19000 (SUM/R1+SUM/R2+SUM/R3+SUM/R4+SUM/R5)

Any help possible, please? I will really appreciated...

```
SELECT q.userid, q.categoryid, sum(q.pointsasall) as ilosc FROM qa_catpoints q 
WHERE (q.categoryid = q.parentid OR q.parentid2 OR q.parentid3 OR q.parentid4) 
group by q.userid, q.categoryid ORDER BY q.userid ASC
```

TABLE STRUCTURE:

```
CREATE TABLE `qa_catpoints` (
  `categoryid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `catname` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `parentid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parentid2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parentid3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parentid4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pointsasall` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pointsasall2` int(11) NOT NULL
)
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT AFTER SUCCESS QUERY:

[image: expect output (corrected)]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: SELECT q.userid, q.categoryid, sum(q.pointsasall) as sumall
FROM qa_catpoints q
WHERE
(q.categoryid = q.parentid OR q.parentid2 OR q.parentid3 OR q.parentid4)
group by q.userid, q.categoryid  
ORDER BY `q`.`userid` ASC

Something like this, but it only give me rows with limited catids . And I need all catids ...

Comment: Can you provide the complete table structure?

Comment: done, edited post

Comment: Can you also please post the expected output of your example ?

Comment: posted, edited post

Comment: @vendettamit - do You know how to set this query ? :)

Comment: @shrek - or maybe You know? :)